# ディレクトリ内を再帰的に全置換する時の選択肢

Tags: unix

**ディレクトリ内を再帰的に全置換する際、grepを使用するかfindを使用するかいつも迷うのですが**
・下記は同じ意味ですか？

```
grep -rl 置換前 . | xargs sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g'

find . -type f - | xargs sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g'　

find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g' {} +　

find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g' {} \
```

---

・基本的には、findの方がファイルタイプを指定できるので、出来ることが多い？
・ディレクトリ名やファイル名の置換はgrepでは出来ない？

Comment: 想定している置換対象は「ファイルの中身」で合っていますか？それとも何か方法があるなら「ファイル名やディレクトリ名を置換する」方法も知りたいということでしょうか。

Comment: 4つ目の「\」は「\;」の間違いでしょうか

Comment: @cubick。Qを分けていなかったので紛らわしいですが、上で想定している置換対象は「ファイルの中身」です。それとは別に下では、「ファイル名やディレクトリ名の置換」はfindでしか出来ないかどうかを知りたい(grepでも出来る？？)、という意味です

Comment: @re9 find コマンドの -exec オプションに対する指定として `;` があるのですが、これを bash でそのまま打つと bash コマンド側のセミコロンだと解釈されてしまうので、エスケープして `\;` と書きます。

Comment: @ nekketsuuu。「\;」は「;」のエスケープなのですね。「\」に意味があるのかと思い、良く分からず質問にそのまま書いてしまいました

Comment: ＠int32_t。4つ目の「\」は「\;」の間違いです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4つのコマンドは、それぞれ異なる動作をします。

- `grep | xargs sed` は、同じファイルを二度走査することになる無駄があります。一度の走査で済む他3つのコマンドに比べ、ファイルサイズが大きくなると速度差が出てくるでしょう。
- `grep | xargs sed` と `find | xargs sed` は、意図しているように動かない可能性があります。たとえばファイル名に半角スペースが含まれている場合、パイプで一旦ただの文字列に戻ってしまうので `sed` 側に正しく認識されません。これが `find` コマンドの `-exec` オプションが必要な理由です。以下は上手くいかない例です。

  ```sh
  $ echo foo > aaa
  $ echo foo > bbb
  $ echo foo > 'ccc ddd'
  $ ls
  aaa  bbb  ccc ddd
  $ find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
  sed: can't read ./ccc: No such file or directory
  sed: can't read ddd: No such file or directory
  $
  ```

  また、この回答では詳説しませんが、この問題を解決するために `find` の[区切り文字を変える方法](https://stackoverflow.com/a/864330/5989200)があります。
- `grep | xargs sed` と `find | xargs sed` は、置換対象のファイルが存在しなかった場合の挙動が他と違います。この2つは該当するファイルが存在しなくても `sed` を実行し、入力ファイルが無いというエラーを出しますが、他の2つはこの場合 `sed` を実行しません。以下は動作例です。

  ```sh
  $ ls
  aaa  bbb  ccc ddd
  $ find . -type f -name xxx | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
  sed: no input files
  $ find . -type f -name xxx -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' \;
  $
  ```
- Qiita の記事[「find の -exec optionの末尾につく \; と + の違い。」](https://qiita.com/ironsand/items/0aed2ffca295706cab69)で触れられているように、`;` と `+` では見つかったファイル名をひとつずつ渡すか、ある程度まとめて渡すかの違いがあります。`+` を使うと実行する `sed` インスタンスの数を減らすことができます。

よって、基本的には `find` コマンドの `-exec` オプションを使うのが安全だと思います。